# PyTorch model get same minimum prediction value

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, pytorch-dataloader

my PyTorch model predict same value as minimum every time !
the model works most of time, but when the labeling data is low the model will keeping predict the lowest minimum as 7666.0977

here is my code :

```
            
        
            for epoch in range(num_epochs):
                
                running_loss = 0.0
                for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
                    try:
                        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
                        inputs, labels = data 

                        # forward + backward + optimize
                        pred = pytorch_model(inputs)
                        pred = torch.reshape(pred, (-1,))
                        pred = pred.requires_grad_(True)
                        loss = loss_funcation(pred, labels)
                        loss_values.append(loss.item())
                        optimizer.zero_grad()                    
                        loss.backward()
                        pytorch_model.float()
                        optimizer.step()
                        
                    except BaseException :
                        print(BaseException)
                        
                    if ((i%1000) == 0 ) :
                        print(i)
                        print(labels)
                        print(pred)
                        print(repeat_time)

                        if (pred[0] >= 123):
                            pytorch_model_scripted = torch.jit.trace(pytorch_model, inputs)
                            pytorch_model_scripted.save('torch_model/aihouse_rent_model_pytoch.pt')
                        else :
                            pytorch_model = torch.jit.load('torch_model/aihouse_rent_model_pytoch.pt')
                            pytorch_model.eval()
```

the training logs (upper tensor is label, the lower is prediction) :

```
tensor([ 7500., 11999., 21000.,  8000.,  4000.,  6300.,  8000.,  8500.,  8999.,
        25000., 50000.,  6000.,  4500.,  7999., 20000., 40000., 35000.,  7000.,
        29999., 31000., 23000.,  7000., 10999.,  6000.,  6000.,  7500., 13000.,
         8500., 10500., 54000., 13000.,  7800.])
tensor([ 9703.4668,  7800.1328, 42964.7070,  7666.0977,  7666.0977, 10141.6621,
        15079.7002, 21295.8457,  7666.0977, 30703.4883, 82036.3906, 11040.0381,
         7666.0977,  7666.0977, 26572.6562, 48481.0430, 55711.0742,  7759.3750,
        36356.5352, 56007.0430, 37348.5508, 16430.8281,  7749.2578,  7666.0977,
        14576.0732, 12882.2256,  7666.0977,  7666.0977,  7666.0977, 61054.1133,
        32916.7070,  7666.0977], grad_fn=<ReshapeAliasBackward0>)

tensor([15500., 10000., 20000.,  7000.,  9999., 26999.,  8500., 15000., 10000.,
        65000.,  6500., 12000., 12888., 16000.,  7500., 21999., 10000., 23888.,
        15000.,  9000., 13000.,  7500., 14500., 27000., 75000., 17000.,  6999.,
        22000., 18000., 25000., 28000., 22500.])
tensor([ 20998.7949,  21992.5000,  18757.2910,   7666.0977,   7901.4912,
         41483.3633,   7666.0977,  29147.5703,   7666.0977, 105128.9531,
          9836.7090,   7666.0977,   7818.9829,  18220.0723,   7666.0977,
         40907.5430,   8166.9707,  15532.2988,  24631.4180,   9088.6553,
         19447.5078,  16831.1992,  22024.0742,  21132.0469,  19458.3652,
         15550.3984,   9073.1377,  43713.2539,  43721.1641,  33740.7383,
         41425.0312,  25237.2188], grad_fn=<ReshapeAliasBackward0>)
```

Does anyone know what the problem is ?
my pytorch version is 2.0.0+cpu, the model structure is like this :

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.fc1_bn=nn.BatchNorm1d(556)
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(556, 2020)
        self.activation1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(2020, 2022)
        self.activation2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(2022, 2020)
        self.activation3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(2020, 2020)
        self.activation4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout4 = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.linear5 = nn.Linear(2020, 2022)
        self.activation5 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout5 = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.linear6 = nn.Linear(2022, 2020)
        self.activation6 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout6 = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.linear7 = nn.Linear(2020, 1)
```